# Indexing JSON or XML

Tags: xml, json, nosql, redis

What is the widely used technique in indexing a `JSON` or `XML` string when storing it on a NoSQL database like `Redis`?

I know database like `MongoDB` provides this already, but I want to understand how to implement this when I will be using a Key-value store, like `Redis` or `Voldemort`.

Such that:

- It will allow a smooth search or query for node entity key or values

Answer (score 1):

With a pure key/value store, you are supposed to maintain an additional set of keys to simulate a secondary index.

For instance you can store:

```
user:1   ->   { id:1, firstname:Bilbo, lastname:Baggins, race:hobbit }
user:2   ->   { id:2, firstname:Peregrin, lastname:Took, race:hobbit }
```

and then:

```
firstname:Bilbo   -   > [1]
lastname:Baggins     -> [1]
firstname:Peregrin   -> [2]    
lastname:Took        -> [2]
race:hobbit          -> [1,2]
```

To find hobbit users, get the value of race:hobbit, and then for each returned id, get user:id.

Of course with a pure key/value store (memcached for instance), it is difficult to manage indexes with low cardinalities (ie. lots of entries for a given value).

With Redis, it is easier due to its support of set and hash datatypes. Also, intersection/union of redis sets is a convenient way to implement queries with logical AND/OR expressions.

See also the following questions:

[how to have relations many to many in redis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10907942/how-to-have-relations-many-to-many-in-redis/10917710#10917710)

[Porting from SQLite to Redis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10794142/porting-from-sqlite-to-redis/10795541#10795541)

Project Voldemort also supports list storage that can be used for a similar purpose (provided there are not too many entries per value).